# Git repo tracking multiple directories

Tags: git, github, directory, tracking, repo

I have a git repo, and whenever I go through the process of committing and pushing up changes, the repo also tracks and pushes a completely separate directory. The two directories are not related at all, and they are in completely separate folders. It won't let me run a *git rm -r* to remove the directory from the commit -- it throws an "fatal: /directory: '/directory' is outside repository" error, even though it was clearly in the repository because it pushed that directory to Git.

How can I disconnect the repo from the unneeded directory?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a symbolic link to the separate directory inside the Git repo? What does the output of `ls -altr` show for the first directory?

Comment: `git push` does not push files or directories: it pushes *commits*. The receiving Git does whatever it is programmed to do, with those commits. If the receiving Git is copying the contents of those commits to two locations, that's what it's been told to do, probably in a deployment script, and you'd have to adjust the deployment script in the receiving Git.